# F#: Detecting errors in regex patterns

Tags: regex, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first .NET language.

As a beginner's project, I would like to write an application asking the user to enter a regex pattern and then flagging any errors.

I have looked through the Regex API on MSDN but there doesn't seem to be any methods that would automatically detect any errors in regex patterns. Will more experienced programmers kindly share with me how they would go about accomplishing this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to check if a regex compiles or not, simply use [try-with](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233194.aspx) block. If you need to check if a regex pattern matches your input string, use `IsMatch()` or `.Success`. That is quite enough.

An example with code taken from another SO post, but with an error in regex pattern where I replaced `(http:\/\/\S+)` with `(http:\/\/\S+`:

```
try
    let testString = "http://www.bob.com http://www.b.com http://www.bob.com http://www.bill.com"

    let matches input =
        Regex.Matches(input, "(http:\/\/\S+") 
        |> Seq.cast<Match>
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun m -> m.Value)
        |> Seq.map (fun (value, groups) -> value, (groups |> Seq.length))
with
    | :? System.Exception as ex -> printfn "Exception! %s " (ex.Message); None
```

More on F# exception raising can be found [here](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/exceptions/) or [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Exception_Handling).

Comment: Actually it's [`try`...`with`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233194.aspx) in F# but otherwise this answer is correct, there's nothing like `TryParse` in the `Regex` class. You'll get an `ArgumentException` if the pattern is incorrect.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Sorry for try-catch, replaced and added a link.

Comment: Thanks, @stribizhev. As I am still unfamiliar with F#, can you kindly provide me with an example of how you'd write the try-with block? Thank you.